# S3 objects are not updating

Tags: amazon-s3

I uploaded lambda code in zip file into a S3 bucket. Now after I update the lambda code and upload it to the same s3 bucket I still see the same old lambda code upon accessing the bucket URL. What could be the reason and where am I failing here?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I tried, but didnt help.